# How do I read and display a file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the code to open the file, but how do I display what is in the file in my shell.

```
outputFile = open('test.txt', 'r')
data = outputFile.read
outputFile.close
```

Comment: See [this example](https://realpython.com/read-write-files-python/#reading-and-writing-opened-files) of opening and printing `dog_breeds.txt`.

Answer (score 2):

- You need to use `()` to call the `read` and `close` methods.  `outputFile.read` is a function; `outputFile.read()` is the result of actually calling that function (i.e. reading data from the file).
- `print` the `data` that you get from calling `read()` if you want to see it in the console.

```
outputFile = open('test.txt', 'r')
data = outputFile.read()
outputFile.close()
print(data)
```

```
Hello world!
```

If you use `outputFile` as a context manager (via the `with` keyword), you don't need to call `close()`; the context is automatically closed at the end of the indented block.

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as outputFile:
    print(outputFile.read())
```

```
Hello world!
```

Answer (score 1):

Well this should work:

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    contents = f.read()
    print(contents)
```

Comment: import os +

with open('test.txt') as f:
    contents = f.read()
    print(contents)